# gyp: binding.gyp not found

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to install the necessary modules for running my web application. I am getting the following error while running `$npm install` :

```
john@mylaptop frontend % npm install              

> fsevents@2.3.2 install /Users/john/workspace/myproject/frontend/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /Users/john/workspace/myproject/frontend/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/john/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/john/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node" "/Users/john/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/john/workspace/myproject/frontend/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
john@mylaptop frontend % node-gyp rebuild --verbose
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/Users/john/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/john/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node-gyp',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
gyp info using node@6.11.0 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION 
gyp ERR! stack /Users/john/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/create-config-gypi.js:18
gyp ERR! stack async function getBaseConfigGypi ({ gyp, nodeDir }) {
gyp ERR! stack       ^^^^^^^^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
gyp ERR! stack     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
gyp ERR! stack     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
gyp ERR! stack     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/john/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:10:26)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/john/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node" "/Users/john/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--verbose"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/john/workspace/myproject/frontend
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
gyp ERR! Node-gyp failed to build your package.
gyp ERR! Try to update npm and/or node-gyp and if it does not help file an issue with the package author.
```

This is the node version I am using :

```
john@mylaptop frontend % npm version
{ frontend: '0.0.0',
  npm: '3.10.10',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  http_parser: '2.7.0',
  icu: '58.2',
  modules: '48',
  node: '6.11.0',
  openssl: '1.0.2k',
  uv: '1.11.0',
  v8: '5.1.281.102',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

I don't want to upgrade npm or node versions for [compatibility reasons](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3) with angular 4.4.6. Any help please. node was installed via nvm and not with brew.

Answer (score 2):

Add file `binding.gyp`

```js
{
  'targets': [
    {
      'target_name': 'bindings',
      'sources': [ 'bindings.node' ],
      'cflags!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],
      'cflags_cc!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],
      'conditions': [
        ['OS=="mac"', {
          'xcode_settings': {
            'GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS': 'YES'
          }
        }]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and rebuid node-gyp. `$ node-gyp rebuild`

Comment: Can you please explain what this does?